# problem about almost sure convergence

Tags: probability

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample for a $uniform(0,\theta)$ distribution. Let $Y_n = max\{X_1,...,X_n\} $. I've proven that $Y_n$ converges in probability to $\theta$. So I'm trying to prove that $Y_n$ converges to $\theta$ almost surely. I tried using the definition but I couldn't get anywhere. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an outline:

Clearly, $(Y_n(\omega))$ is nondecreasing for each $\omega$, so it converging to $\theta$ almost surely amounts to it eventually being larger than $\theta-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$, which amounts to it being eventually larger than $\theta-1/n$ for every positive natural number.

So let $A_n=\{\omega:Y_m(\omega)>\theta-1/n$ for some $m\}$. You have t show that the probability of $\bigcap_n A_n$ is $1$. For this, it suffices to show that the probability of each $A_n$ is $1$. To show this, show that the probability can not be strictly smaller than $1$.